# A Ruby on Rails framework which can be used for website for an event organizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

I once build a webshop in Rails using the Spree framework. This was great since everything I needed for a webshop came out of the box. Now I want to make a website for people who organize dance parties. The site should have information of the new line-up and location, pictures/videos of older parties, and the possibility to buy new tickets.

I hope if you think of something that can be used which is like what Spree is for a webshop but then for the above requirements I would be very happy if you could share it with me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is a good framework for this.

Meaning I can't think of anything premade to help you accomplish this, but it doesn't sound difficult to do from scratch.

Comment: Haha I was actually thinking the same thing. Maybe there is something though. Thanks ;)

Comment: How would you go about creating an admin area in Rails where pictures and videos can be managed?

Comment: Got it! ActiveAdmin or RailsAdmin seem to be good options.